# Factory actor pattern

Tags: scala, akka

Earlier I read that creating root(after /user/) actor (system.actorOf) is expensive.

Is there a common pattern to create ClientFactoryActor which main responsibility is simply return new actor on request(for example we need new websocket actor per client etc.)?

Comment: And don't forget to kill actors to avoid memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed you should try to maintain a hierarchy of actors for the error handling purposes (different supervision strategies)
One of the convenient ways to create an actor is to have a companion object that returns a reference to the wanted actor instantiated with the given parameters (singleton factory)

```
    object DemoActor {
      /**
       * Create Props for an actor of this type.
       *
       * @param magicNumber The magic number to be passed to this actor’s constructor.
       * @return a Props for creating this actor, which can then be further configured
       *         (e.g. calling `.withDispatcher()` on it)
       */
      def props(magicNumber: Int): Props = Props(new DemoActor(magicNumber))
    }

    class DemoActor(magicNumber: Int) extends Actor {
      def receive = {
        case x: Int => sender() ! (x + magicNumber)
      }
    }

    class SomeOtherActor extends Actor {
      // Props(new DemoActor(42)) would not be safe
      context.actorOf(DemoActor.props(42), "demo")
      // ...
    }
```

One good starting point is the [Akka documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.8/scala/actors.html#actor-lifecycle-scala) page.